# Provide a VB6 object for window.external in a WebBrowser-hosted page

Tags: javascript, vba, vb6, webbrowser-control, window.external

With the .NET WebBrowser control we can do:

```
WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new a_class();
```

where `a_class` is declared as `[ComVisible(True)]`.

After which the instance of `a_class` is accessible to the javascript in the page under the name of `window.external`.

**How do I achieve the same with the VB6/VBA WebBrowser OCX control?**

There is apparently no direct property to set.

There *are* `WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow` and `WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.external` objects, both are not `null` (provided the page has loaded), but assigning an instance of something to the latter results in

> Runtime error 445
>   Object doesn't support this action.

Just to rule it out, I made the class I want to pass [implement the `IObjectSafety` interface](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182598), but that didn't do anything (the `IObjectSafety` members are not even called).

I also tried inspecting the existing `parentWindow.external` object with TypeLib Information. `ClassClassInfoFromObject` fails with "Doesn't support automation or required interface," `InterfaceInfoFromObject` fails with "Subscript out of range."

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to do in VB6. You have to implement `IDocHostUIHandler` interface on the site object of the `WebBrowser` control and return an `IDispatch` from `GetExternal` method. The site object is provided by the VB6 form so you have to hook `QueryInterface` on its `IUnknown` to provide (some) custom implementation of `IDocHostUIHandler` on VB6's site object.

Here is direct copy/paste of an implementation I did some time ago: https://gist.github.com/wqweto/5065624

You'll need `VBOleGuids3` typelib and a bit of code cleanup to make it compile as a separate project.

Comment: It would seem `VBOleGuids3` is only known to Google because you posted this answer :) Where can I get it from? Also, this won't work in VBA unless precompiled with VB6 because of no VBControlExtender support, right?

Comment: I wouldn't dare this code in VBA. Try http://www.vbaccelerator.com/typelib.htm for typelibs -- will need `threadapi.tlb` too.